# How to get monthly archive posts in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

In My wordpress blog I can get all the archive list in monthly view. But after click month link it dose not show the blog post in that month. it just refreshing the page. Is there any php file to add or  function?
So how to get all post in particular month that click the month link in archive list?

EX: when I click 'June' link in archive list it dose not shows post in June. It just refresh the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a by default Archives Widgets installed in wordpress you just need to put that widgets in the sidebar wherever you want to display the Archive posts.

```
register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Primary Widget Area', 'twentyten' ),
        'id' => 'primary-widget-area',
        'description' => __( 'The primary widget area', 'twentyten' ),
        'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</li>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );
```

Register a sidebar in your themes function.php and then assign that widgets in that sidebar.

Here is the code of archive.php file under themes

```
    <?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Archive pages.
 *
 * Used to display archive-type pages if nothing more specific matches a query.
 * For example, puts together date-based pages if no date.php file exists.
 *
 * Learn more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Ten
 * @since Twenty Ten 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

        <div id="container">
            <div id="content" role="main">

<?php
    /* Queue the first post, that way we know
     * what date we're dealing with (if that is the case).
     *
     * We reset this later so we can run the loop
     * properly with a call to rewind_posts().
     */
    if ( have_posts() )
        the_post();
?>

            <h1 class="page-title">
<?php if ( is_day() ) : ?>
                <?php printf( __( 'Daily Archives: <span>%s</span>', 'twentyten' ), get_the_date() ); ?>
<?php elseif ( is_month() ) : ?>
                <?php printf( __( 'Monthly Archives: <span>%s</span>', 'twentyten' ), get_the_date( 'F Y' ) ); ?>
<?php elseif ( is_year() ) : ?>
                <?php printf( __( 'Yearly Archives: <span>%s</span>', 'twentyten' ), get_the_date( 'Y' ) ); ?>
<?php else : ?>
                <?php _e( 'Blog Archives', 'twentyten' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
            </h1>

<?php
    /* Since we called the_post() above, we need to
     * rewind the loop back to the beginning that way
     * we can run the loop properly, in full.
     */
    rewind_posts();

    /* Run the loop for the archives page to output the posts.
     * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
     * called loop-archive.php and that will be used instead.
     */
     get_template_part( 'loop', 'archive' );
?>

            </div><!-- #content -->
        </div><!-- #container -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>


archive.php
```

Comment: in Widgets ares it says "No Sidebars Defined" but I made sidebar.php file? how to solve it?

Comment: That works well. but even after put that widgets in the sidebar not show the posts under that month. It will just refresh the not showing posts. EX: when I click 'June' link in archive list it dose not shows post in June.

Comment: I think you have changed the Archie.php file in the theme.Please share your site url in case its live

Comment: Can you please explain how Archive.php looks like. Is there any special function to call? because Site is still not live.

Comment: I have edited the answer once again with the archive.php code